# Where am I supposed ask questions regarding Physics education/research?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

I asked this as a soft question [How to explore Physics research as an undergraduate, keeping in mind the ever increasing weightage on publications?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/473751/)

I have explictly asked if this is the right place to post this and if not please suggest an alternative. One of the contributors suggested "Academia" and I have posted the same question there. The question has been downvoted and there is vote to close the question.

(The problem I see with Academia is lack of subject specific soft-questions.)

But I do not understand why this is not a right question for "soft-question" tag. In the tag-info it is written that we can ask questions asking for advice regarding publication, physics research/study. But I do not understand why my question is not related to Physics research/study technique.

Does it have to be a Physics research problem/homework problem which can be solved without Physics or does the above sentence mean - doubts regarding doing research in Physics?

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7551/44126

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure exactly what you're asking, but one of the main references on education questions is [this one](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/what-kind-of-education-questions-should-we-allow), which points out that many questions about education are overly broad or opinion-based. I believe the question you asked is among them. That's why it's off topic here.

The matter of the [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag is a separate one, and entirely irrelevant to whether your question is on topic here or not. Bear in mind that tag descriptions are *not* what determines whether a question is on topic here.